# Preparing a conda environment for a different platform with no internet

Tags: python, anaconda, offline

I'm trying to prepare a relatively simple python environment environment using anaconda. I need to build the environment as similar as possible on both Win-64 & Linux-64 platforms. The catch is that the linux system is behind a strict firewall that essentially results in no internet access.

Here's what I do have:

- Anaconda 23.03-01 installed on both system
- The environment successfully created on windows
- The environment file exported using --from-history

My environment file is basically:

- python=3.9
- numpy
- scipy
- pandas
- pyro5

I've tried changing my channels & conda_subdir variable to linux-64 (while running on windows) and it appears to have downloaded the right packages, but obviously fails on the install.

I suspect my best option is to create a custom channel by downloading the proper packages myself, moving this to the linux system, then installing from there. In order to keep this process stream-lined, **is there an easy way to search for dependencies, download the packages necessary, and create a channel that supports both win-64 & linux-64 platforms, all from the windows pc**? Then I can place that channel in a shared location and create my environment on either platform by pointing to it.

Alternatively, is there an easier method I'm overlooking?